# How to provide variable based search for "IN" condition Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

I am using BigQuery console for this query which is working fine:

```
SELECT values, cities FROM x.y.z WHERE values IN (1,2,3)
```

I am not sure why this is not working as expected

```
declare var1 Array<INT64>;
set var1 = (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT distinct values FROM `a.b.c`));
SELECT values, cities FROM x.y.z WHERE values IN UNNEST(var1)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just had extra `SELECT` in your second line - try below

```
declare var1 Array<INT64>;
set var1 = ARRAY(SELECT distinct values FROM `a.b.c`);
SELECT values, cities FROM x.y.z WHERE values IN UNNEST(var1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use an inner join instead:

```
select values, cities from x.y.z inner join (select distinct values as dv from a.b.c) t on values = dv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare var1 Array<INT64>;
set var1 = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(distinct values) FROM `a.b.c`);
SELECT values, cities FROM x.y.z WHERE values IN UNNEST(var1)
```